# Using intent to share data from different apps

Tags: android, android-intent

I have made an image upload app .In that i want that if user goes to gallery and if he selects on share button ,my app should be there.For that i have used intents.But when ever i am trying to get that image i am getting it as null??.Why this is happening.

Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".Home.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*"></data>
                <data android:mimeType="application/doc"></data>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Home Activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        leftDrawer = MenuDrawer.attach(this, MenuDrawer.Type.OVERLAY, Position.LEFT);
        leftDrawer.setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
        leftDrawer.setTouchMode(MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_WINDOW);
        leftDrawer.setMenuView(R.layout.menu_drawer);

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        startFragment(new UploadButton(), "", "", false);
        intent = new Intent();
        imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        Log.e("Image Uri",""+imageUri);
        if (imageUri != null) {
            replaceFragment(new UploadDocument());
        }
```

Comment: `intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);` : Where did you get that from? In other words, are you sure that's the way you should be trying to retrieve the image URI from the `Intent`?

Comment: i dont know, i read it some where that this should be used

Comment: I've added an answer.

Comment: @Squonk Thanks it working fine,please make add a post so that i can tick mark it

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer below. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't spot it immediately in your code...

```
intent = new Intent();
imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

The above code is creating a new (empty) `Intent` so it obviously isn't going to contain any extras. Get rid of the line `intent = new Intent();` and instead use `getIntent()` in the second line in order to get the `Intent` which was used to start your `Activity` as follows...

```
imageUri = (Uri) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```